# How do I measure message delay between multiple applications running on a multicore system?

Tags: c++, winapi, timing

I am developing a system that is comprised of three major software components. A client application, a core application, and a exchange application all running on the same server. Messages are received at the client app, relayed to the core app and then forwarded to the appropriate exchange app.

I would like to measure message latency internal to our system, so timestamp a message when it is received at the client, at the core and a timestamp when the message is sent out from the exchange module.

Is it reasonable to use QueryPerformanceCounter() to time events across multiple applications? It seems that the counter would not be reliable across applications running multiple cores.

Comment: Generally, on modern CPU architectures, QueryPerformanceCounter() is reliable across threads/processes.  See the "Remarks" section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I agree with @Chad. My experience on modern multi-core and even multi-processor computers has been that `QueryPerformanceCounter` is reliable on any machine that's less than about 7 years old. I had some trouble with early multi-processor machines (2004 and 2005), but haven't seen any problems with modern hardware.

Comment: Thanks @Chad/@Jim for the info. It does appear my measurements are reliable across processes. The curious part is that I am actually seeing consistent message latencies between 350-450 usec. Which seems a little too good. But running the test over 10000 msgs I would have thought that I would see huge jumps in the performance counter or even negative time reported if the count wasn't coherent across processes and threads.

Comment: So, you are surprised at the consistent good (relative) performance of your application?  350-450 usec with local interprocess communication is pretty good, but not shockingly so (though I have no experience in your problem domain).

Comment: I suppose I just had no reference point, but the results did seem very good. But after you put it so frankly I feel more confident about the tests. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding an exchange app that opens a client connection and then circulates one time-stamped message around, say, 10000 times.  The delays will add up and so you can then effectively use a wall-time stamp, calculate end-start and divide by 10000.

Comment: That is an interesting idea. Would you agree trying to use QueryPerformanceCounter() across multiple threads, let alone multiple applications is unreliable?

Answer (score 0):

As Chad points out, QueryPerformanceCounter works fine for this purpose.  From MSDN "In general, the performance counter results [from QPC] are consistent across all processors in multi-core and multi-processor systems, even when measured on different threads or processes. "  Only a couple exceptions are mentioned...

1. Pre-vista operating systems that run on certain processors might violate this consistency...
2. Different threads might be off by 1 tick.  "the term tick refers to a period of time equal to 1 ÷ (the frequency of the performance counter obtained from QueryPerformanceFrequency)."